# Getting navigation.navigate cant find variable navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am very new to react native. I want to open drawer on button click but getting error navigation.navigate cant find variable navigation.
I tried this.props.navigation also but no use.

Below is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeContainer from './HomeContainer';


const Manager = StackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
   screen: HomeContainer,
     navigationOptions: {
      // header: null,
      headerTitle: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={35} onPress={ () =>{ navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}} />

    },
  },
});

export default Manager;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try as follows,

```
import React from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';
import HomeContainer from './HomeContainer';


const Manager = StackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
   screen: HomeContainer,
     navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      // header: null,
      headerTitle: 'Home',
      headerLeft: <Icon name="menu" size={35} onPress={ () =>{ navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}} />

    })
  }
});

export default Manager;
```

`navigationOptions` now returns function instead of object, `navigation` will be part of object passed as argument to this function.

Hope this will help!